# How to make typescript definitions that work with angular2fire observable responses?

Tags: angular, typescript, firebase-realtime-database, angularfire2

I'm building an Angular2 app on Firebase using angularfire2.

Items returned from the realtime db have additional fields on them (e.g. $key, $exists) that can be useful in your application. But if you don't include those keys in your model definitions, typescript throws errors.

For example, say I have a class called item:

```
export class Item {
  name: string,
  price: number,
  isOnSale: boolean
}
```

When that item is returned via angularfire2 it has additional firebase fields (e.g. $key, $exists, etc.), that I sometimes want to access:

```
constructor(private af: AngularFire){
  this.af.database.list('items').subscribe(items => {
    items.forEach(item => this.doSomethingWithDbItem(item));
  })
}

doSomethingWithDbItemAndThenUpdate(item: Item){
  // Now, if I want to access the $key field, I get a typescript error because
  // $key does not exist on my class definition

  if( item.name === 'toy_truck'){
    const key = item.$key; // Will throw error typescript compile error
    this.af.database.object(`items/${key}`).set({isOnSale: true})
  }
}
```

Is there a best practice for handling this? I could add the db keys directly to the model.  Or maybe create a FB class that has $key, $exists, etc. and then have my Item class and other classes extend FB?

This is a bit of a contrived example, so code may not be exactly right, but hopefully my point/question is clear.

Comment: and what's wrong with specifying $key and $exists properties on the Item interface?

Comment: you could add them as optional properties of they aren't there all the time. :)

Comment: @toskv I could add the to the Item interface, but I have many models/db nodes and would need to add them to all, which seems redundant. So I was thinking of a base class. That would be my approach but i was wondering if there was a better way.

Comment: switching to interfaces is a better way of doing it. check out @cartant 's solution is the cleanest way in my opinion. :)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The `items` in this code:

```ts
this.af.database.list('items').subscribe(items => {
  items.forEach(item => this.doSomethingWithDbItem(item));
})
```

will be an array of `Object` instances. It will not be an array of `Item` instances. That is, `item instanceof Item` will be `false`.

So it doesn't make a lot of sense to tell TypeScript that that's what they are.

Instead, you should use interfaces to describe the *shape* of the models. And if you were to use interfaces, using a base interface with the AngularFire2 properties is trivial:

```ts
export interface AngularFireObject {
  $exists: () => boolean;
  $key: string;
  $value?: any;
}

export interface Item extends AngularFireObject {
  name: string;
  price: number;
  isOnSale: boolean;
}
```

Comment: I see, I was using classes when what I should use is an interface. Thanks! @cartant